# Sending raw byte buffer post

Tags: php, c++, curl, libcurl

I am trying to figure out how can I send in C++ using the curl easy, a `BYTE[100]` buffer, which might contain `0x00` bytes, to a POST field to a PHP script.
I'm also in need in using the HTML compression technique.

Prior this, I was doing `sprintf("%02X")` on each bytes so I could send them in letters, but now I need to minimize the network traffic in order to improve the API response time.

I tried on Google but so far no resources that is close to my question.
Isn't it possible to send it even without a POST field?
I just need to send my ray BYTE[] and get it from my PHP script.

Comment: And a post field can accept a 0x00 byte? it will terminate the string, please read carefuly my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with a PUT solution this way.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, szURL);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, reader);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)dwBinarySize);
```

Your CURLOPT_READFUNCTION "reader" function needs to feed the binary data, look up the documentation at curl for more info.

And you get the binary data you sent in PHP this way:

```
$fPut = fopen("php://input", "r");

$bInput;
while ($data = fread($fPut, 8192))
    $bInput .= $data;

fclose($fPut);
```